# rpm spec file "Suggests" statement

Tags: version, rpm, requirements, rpm-spec

I am currently refurbishing a lot of outdated specfiles, and I remember talking about soft dependencies, which would come in handy for a current specfile (i.e. lighttpd suggesting the most popular modules to be installed, like mod_rewrite, mod_redirect).

My main issue is, google seems to fail to release any bit of valuable information on the **implementation status of the `Suggests:` statement, its current overall status and rpm version requirements**. Most documents and howtos are from 2004 and earlier, too outdated to be considered a trustable source. The absolute rpm pdf does not state anything about the `Suggests:` tag either.

Thanks a lot for any information in advance.

Post scriptum: OpenSuSE & Mageia seem to use it, but beyond that..

https://build.opensuse.org/package/view_file?file=meld.spec&package=meld&project=openSUSE%3AFactory

https://wiki.mageia.org/en/Packaging_for_beginners

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A message on a mailing list indicates `rpm 4.4.3` introduced it

http://www.redhat.com/archives/rpm-list/2006-January/msg00034.html